# Can we do `a = b || c` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know if we can express "if the first is null, then choose the second."

```
foo = bar || doe 
#if bar is nil, foo = doe
```

Comment: What happened when you tried running that bit of code? My guess is that you will get a boolean.

Comment: yes, you should be able to do that!

Comment: It is Ruby question rather the Rails

Comment: Note: yes, works as is, but be very sure that bar is not holding a boolean value, or you might get results you were not expecting.  If in doubt use the safer but more ugly `foo = bar.nil? ? doe : bar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. It works as expected:

```
bar = nil
doe = "Hello"
foo = bar || doe
# => "Hello"
```

Comment: good to ear that ;) I couldn't test it in a real context, so I was in doubt with my syntax :) What kind of values makes ruby choose the second ? nil, false and "null" ?

Comment: `false` or `nil`. Not `""` or 0.

Answer (score 4):

well, yea. `a ||= b` is the equivalent of `a = a || b` if the first element is `nil` or `false` then the result is the second element.

Comment: This is not right. `a = a || b` is not equal to `foo = bar || doe`, but it equals to `foo = foo || doe`.

Comment: Did you read the answer carefully? You might try again. I said that `a ||= b` is equivalent to `a = a || b`. And the QS already knows about `||=` so the equivalency should answer his question.

Comment: Well I may be mistaken but how can you write `foo = bar || doe` like `a ||= b`?

Comment: No, you can't, but the basic principle of the || operator remains the same be it in `a ||= b` or in `a = b || c `